# SQL - left join SELECT with SELECT COUNT(*)

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to count the number of rows in track_plays that have a particular track_ID and join this in with my query that selects lots of data from various tables.

Here's what I have so far;

```
SELECT
    T.ID,
    T.url,
    T.name,
    T.pic,
    T.T_ID,

    COUNT(P.T_ID) AS plays,
    S.Status, 

    G.gig_name,
    G.date_time,
    G.lineup,
    G.price,
    G.ticket,

    E.action,
    E.ID,
    E.timestamp,
    E.E_ID

FROM
    events E
    LEFT JOIN 
    TRACKS T
    ON T.ID = E.ID AND E.action = 'has uploaded a track.' AND E.E_ID = T.T_ID

    LEFT JOIN 
    STATUS S
    ON S.ID = E.ID AND E.action = 'has some news.' AND E.E_ID = S.S_ID

    LEFT JOIN 
    GIGS G
    ON G.ID = E.ID AND E.action = 'has posted a gig.' AND E.E_ID = G.G_ID

    LEFT JOIN 
    track_plays P
    ON P.A_ID = E.ID AND E.action = 'has uploaded a track.' AND E.E_ID = P.T_ID

WHERE E.ID = '3'
ORDER BY E.timestamp DESC LIMIT 15
```

Hopeflly that should explain what i am trying to do quicker than words can but basically the `plays` counts the number of plays a track has had. `Events` is the table where all new ID's go for any new content. They are given an action so we can determine what kind of event they are and therefore retrieve data from the correct table(s).

At the moment, with the COUNT in there the query gives something like this

```
ID  name  pic  T_ID  plays ...

3    1     2    44    100
```

The data i have put in there is just representative and it gives more columns than that. The point is though it should give something like this;

```
ID  name  pic  T_ID  plays ...

3    1     2    44    100

3    3     1    48    10

4    8     2    21    86
```

As you can see, with the COUNT in there a lot of the data is taken out.

Please comment if you need anymore detail. I don't want to go into too much detail as it may not be needed and i have a tendency to waffle.

Thanks!

Comment: ```GROUP``` is your friend I think. So the E.ID is the "key" in the result table or did i misunderstand?

Comment: That's what i didn't want to dive into. For the most part of the query E_ID is the "key" but in the case of the play count yes T_id is the "key".

Comment: Sorry... i changed my comment when I saw my mistake...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done, thanks to everyone who helped. I was missing the `GROUP BY` clause.  Now it works like a charm. Here's the finished product:

```
SELECT
    T.ID,
    T.url,
    T.name,
    T.pic,
    T.T_ID,

    COUNT(P.T_ID) AS plays,
    S.Status, 

    G.gig_name,
    G.date_time,
    G.lineup,
    G.price,
    G.ticket,

    E.action,
    E.ID,
    E.timestamp,
    E.E_ID

FROM
    events E
    LEFT JOIN TRACKS T
        ON T.ID = E.ID AND E.action = 'has uploaded a track.' AND E.E_ID = T.T_ID
    LEFT JOIN STATUS S
        ON S.ID = E.ID AND E.action = 'has some news.' AND E.E_ID = S.S_ID
    LEFT JOIN GIGS G
        ON G.ID = E.ID AND E.action = 'has posted a gig.' AND E.E_ID = G.G_ID
    LEFT JOIN track_plays P
        ON P.A_ID = E.ID AND E.action = 'has uploaded a track.' AND E.E_ID = P.T_ID
WHERE E.ID = '3'
GROUP BY T.T_ID
ORDER BY E.timestamp DESC LIMIT 15
```

Answer (score 3):

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263747/incorporate-a-count-together-with-joins-in-mysql/16263979#16263979) as you need an explicit group by. I think you need to add this to your query:

```
...
GROUP BY P.T_ID
```

Comment: So I am unsure on how to use this. Do I want the GROUP BY in the LEFT JOIN or do I want it after it?